# Returning multiple database reults with jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery

Hey Guys.
I am using the jQuery ajax function to send data from a form and return some results.

```
function get(){
    $.post('data.php', { name: $('#name').attr('value'),lname: $('#lname').attr('value')  },
            function (data){

                $('#age').html(data).show();

            });
    }
```

The function posts to data.php.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];

    //DB connect
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password')
     or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    //DB select         
    mysql_select_db("users")
    or die("Could not find database: " . mysql_error());


    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $return_name  =$row['name'];        //set the session for the user login
    $return_lname =$row['lname'];
    $return_age =$row['age'];

    echo $return_name;
    echo $return_lname;
    echo $return_age;
```

The output is all displayed in the #age div but i want to be able to specify each of the three outputs to a different div?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

First, You can use the `val` function to retrieve the values from a form element. For example, instead of `$('#name').attr('value');` you can use `$('#name').val();`

Second, in order to manipulate the data received from your `data.php` script, I recommend to use PHP JSON function like `json_encode`,  like this:

```
//DB connect mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password')
or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); //DB select
mysql_select_db("users") or die("Could not find database: " . mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// encoding array in json format and printing it...
echo json_encode(array("name"=>$row["name"], "lname"=>$row["lname"], "age"=>$row["age"]));
```

Third, you can manipulate the response like this:

```
function get(){ $.post('data.php', { name: $('#name').attr('value'),lname: $('#lname').attr('value') }, function (data){
            $('#div1').html(data.name).show();
            $('#div2').html(data.lname).show();
            $('#div1').html(data.age).show();
         });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find it helpful to use PHP's [JSON functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php). This would allow you to use jQuery to update the proper DIV's.

Your jQuery might look something like this:

```
var name  = $("#name").val();  // May help to set variables first.
var lname = $("#lname").val();

$.post("data.php",
        {name:  name, lname: lname },
        function(data) {
          $("div#name").html(data.name);
          $("div#lname").html(data.lname);
          $("div#age").html(data.age);
        }, "json");
```

Your PHP might look something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$return['name']  = $row['name'];        //set the session for the user login
$return['lname'] = $row['lname'];
$return['age']   = $row['age'];

echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your php database script return json and use your javascript success function to insert the results into the DOM as desired. Here's an example of how to request, generate, and handle a JSON result:

```
<?php
$results = array();
if ($_REQUEST['arg1']) { $results['res1'] = strtoupper($_REQUEST['arg1']); }
if ($_REQUEST['arg2']) { $results['res2'] = strtoupper($_REQUEST['arg2']); }
if (count($results) > 0) { echo json_encode($results); }
else { ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#go').click(function() {
            $.post('test.php', { arg1: 'homer', arg2: 'marge' }, function (data) {
                $('#one').text(data.res1);
                $('#two').html(data.res2);
            }, 'json');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">bart</div>
<div id="two">lisa</div>
<a id="go" href="#"`>go</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php }
```